# 403 status code when logstash on EC2 connect to the ES

Tags: amazon-web-services, logstash, logstash-configuration, aws-elasticsearch

I want to collect logs from my Java application to the AWS Elastic Search using the Logstash based on the t3.small EC2 instance. I install logstash amazon es plugin to the instance. But when I run the Logstash on the EC2 I saw the error with status code 403:

```
[WARN ] 2021-11-06 08:51:29.279 [Ruby-0-Thread-4: :1] amazonelasticsearch - Attempted to resurrect connection to dead ES instance, but got an error. {:url=>"https://search-elastic-seach-v2-dkuei2knqss3qvmo5uzwnudi3m.us-east-2.es.amazonaws.com:443/", :error_type=>LogStash::Outputs::AmazonElasticSearch::HttpClient::Pool::BadResponseCodeError, :error=>"Got response code '403' contacting Elasticsearch at URL 'https://search-elastic-seach-v2-dkuei2knqss3qvmo5uzwnudi3m.us-east-2.es.amazonaws.com:443/'"}
```

My output in the `logstash.conf` looks like:

```
output {
  amazon_es {
    hosts => ["domain.us-east-2.es.amazonaws.com"]
    index => "logstash"

    region => "us-east-2"
    aws_access_key_id => 'KEY'
    aws_secret_access_key => 'sEcReT'
  }
}
```

I use IAM user with permission `AmazonESFullAccess`
My ES cluster has policy:

```
{
  "Version": "2012-10-17",
  "Statement": [
    {
      "Effect": "Allow",
      "Principal": {
        "AWS": [
          "arn:aws:iam::userId:root",
          "arn:aws:iam::userId:user/elastic-search"
        ]
      },
      "Action": "es:*",
      "Resource": "arn:aws:es:us-east-2:userId:domain/my-domain/*"
    }
  ]
}
```

Comment: Is your Elasticsearch cluster inside a VPC or publicly available?

Comment: @ErmiyaEskandary  My cluster is publicly available.

Comment: Try using IAM policy simulator to see if you have the correct permissions for accessing the AWS ElasticSearch apis. Seems like a permissions issue. You also do not need to use both resource and identity based policy. Only identity based policy in this case should work. As a best practise I would recommend using an IAM role with relevant permissions to be attached to Instance Profile rather than storing long term credentials in configuration file.

Comment: On second look the ARNs in resource based policy look incorrect. It should have account id and not userid. Example resource arn `arn:aws:es:us-west-2:111111111111:domain/recipes1/* `

Comment: @karanshah the user Id -> that is my account id. I just do not want to share this information in the question.

Also, I run my `elastic-search` IAM user by the IAM Policy simulator and saw that permission is correct and IAM has access to the `ESHttpGet`, `ESHttpPost`, `ESHttpPut` and `ESHttpDelete`.

After rebooting the EC2 I see the same situation with the 403 status code. 

Can the absence of SSL in the EC2 instance cause the issue?
Because I find an answer that issue can be with EC2 instance.

Comment: @TomashGombosh can you point me to the answer you are referring to here ?
Understand the account id masking
Have you tried using --log.level DEBUG while starting logstash to see if it provides additional information ?

Comment: @karanshah I resolve the issue with a workaround to use not amazon_es but use an Elasticsearch plugin and create an additional user on the ES with restriction access and that started working. 

But when you wrote that comment I try to use a new EC2 with Logstash on the amazon_es and do the same step with policy, installation, and Logstash config, to get the debug log. And that is weird, but my Logstash with amazon_es started working too. I do not know what was the issue with the previous EC2. Honestly, I do the same and it works.

Magic.

Comment: @TomashGombosh that is great news that you have resolved the issue

Comment: @karanshah thank you for your replies and question because without your questions I will not receive a good result.
Thank you.